# Separation of Variables Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

We start with the differential equation $\dfrac{dy}{dx}=e^{3x+4y}$.

We separate into $e^{3x}~dx = e^{4y}~dy$.

We integrate next I integrate to get $1/3 e^{3x} = 1/4 e^{4y}$.

I've gotten this far but I can't get any farther, I'm trying to solve for $y$ and I keep messing up.

Using the information I've been given the answer I get is $y=-1/4 log(4(c-(1/3 e^3x)$.

Did I do anything wrong?

Comment: You separated it wrong.

Comment: So far, I see three mistakes, one of which is mentioned above.

Comment: Could you tell me what the mistakes are?

Comment: Another mistake is integral constant $$\int e^{ax}dx=\frac1ae^{ax}+C$$

Comment: The two comments above mention the three mistakes I found. MyGlasses' comment fixes two of your mistakes.

Comment: @PierreHumbertLeblanc   $ e^{3x}~dx = e^{4y}dy $ >>>>>  $ e^{3x}~dx = e^{ \color{red} {-4y}} dy $